# Why does Entity Framework Migration not read file App.xaml.cs in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, entity-framework-migrations, winui-3

I have a [WinUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_UI_Library) 3 project using GenericHost (based on the default WinUI 3 Visual Studio template):

```csharp
Host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.
    CreateDefaultBuilder().
    UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory).
    ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        // Default Activation Handler
        services.AddTransient<ActivationHandler<LaunchActivatedEventArgs>, DefaultActivationHandler>();

        // Other Activation Handlers
        services.AddTransient<IActivationHandler, AppNotificationActivationHandler>();

        // Services
        services.AddSingleton<IAppNotificationService, AppNotificationService>();
        services.AddSingleton<ILocalSettingsService, LocalSettingsService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IThemeSelectorService, ThemeSelectorService>();

        // Configuration
        services.Configure<LocalSettingsOptions>(context.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(LocalSettingsOptions)));

        services.AddDbContext<WinUIContext>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WinUIContext")));
    }).
    Build();
```

I want to use [Entity Framework Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework#History) and using Migration, but when I try to add migration like below,

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Verbose
```

I didn’t get any errors, but Entity Framework does not create any migration files.

```
Using project 'Source\WinUITest\WinUI3'.
Using startup project 'Source\WinUITest\WinUI3'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile D:\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\bin\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\WinUI3.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\sooro\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages" --runtimeconfig D:\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\bin\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\WinUI3.runtimeconfig.json C:\Users\sooro\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\6.0.19\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll migrations add InitialCreate --json --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly D:\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\bin\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\WinUI3.dll --project D:\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\WinUI3.csproj --startup-assembly D:\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\bin\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\WinUI3.dll --startup-project D:\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\WinUI3.csproj --project-dir D:\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\ --language C# --configuration Debug --working-dir D:\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution --root-namespace WinUI3 --nullable
Using assembly 'WinUI3'.
Using startup assembly 'WinUI3'.
Using application base 'D:\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\bin\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64'.
Using working directory 'D:\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3'.
Using root namespace 'WinUI3'.
Using project directory 'D:\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\'.
Remaining arguments: .
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'WinUI3'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
```

As you can see in details log, Entity Framework does not can find any classes and method.

How to resolve this?

**Note: My full source code is https://github.com/soroshsabz/TestSolution**

**Update 2023-07-11**

As @jeaninez-msft says in a comment, to change the migration command to

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Verbose -Project WinUI3.Data -StartupProject WinUI3
```

I retry migration, and anything does not work too. I attach a new log below:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Verbose -Project WinUI3.Data -StartupProject WinUI3
```

Output:

```
Using project 'Source\WinUITest\WinUI3.Data'.
Using startup project 'Source\WinUITest\WinUI3'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile C:\Users\sooro\Documents\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\bin\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\WinUI3.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\sooro\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages" --runtimeconfig C:\Users\sooro\Documents\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\bin\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\WinUI3.runtimeconfig.json C:\Users\sooro\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\6.0.19\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll migrations add InitialCreate --json --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly C:\Users\sooro\Documents\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\bin\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\WinUI3.Data.dll --project C:\Users\sooro\Documents\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3.Data\WinUI3.Data.csproj --startup-assembly C:\Users\sooro\Documents\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\bin\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\WinUI3.dll --startup-project C:\Users\sooro\Documents\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\WinUI3.csproj --project-dir C:\Users\sooro\Documents\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3.Data\ --language C# --configuration Debug --working-dir C:\Users\sooro\Documents\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution --root-namespace WinUI3.Data --nullable
Using assembly 'WinUI3.Data'.
Using startup assembly 'WinUI3'.
Using application base 'C:\Users\sooro\Documents\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3\bin\x64\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0'.
Using working directory 'C:\Users\sooro\Documents\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3'.
Using root namespace 'WinUI3.Data'.
Using project directory 'C:\Users\sooro\Documents\Source\Repos\soroshsabz\TestSolution\Source\WinUITest\WinUI3.Data\'.
Remaining arguments: .
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'WinUI3'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
```

**Update 2023-07-13**

My DbContext is like below:

```cs
public class WinUIContext : DbContext
{
    public WinUIContext(DbContextOptions<WinUIContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        var folder = Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData;
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
        DbPath = Path.Join(path, "WinUITest.db");
    }

    public DbSet<EntityFirst> EntityFirsts
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public object DbPath
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try to use the `-Project` and `-StartupProject` parameters to explicitly specify the project path and startup project path.

Comment: I do not think it is relevant for my problem, but i try your solution, and update my question, and you can see it.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT please see my repo, if you can and updated question

Comment: Could you please tell us what's the `DbContext classes`?

Comment: You can see inhttps://github.com/soroshsabz/TestSolution

But I update my question to simple see it @Jeaninez-MSFT

Comment: @sorosh_sabz you are not following the Microsoft conventions mentioned in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error. I found a workaround by adding a new project to the solution, with the only purpose to act as the startup project for migrations.

In your case:

1. Add a new project as a simple console application, name it `WinUI3.Data.Startup`
2. Add the NuGet Packages `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` to the just created project
3. Add the `WinUI3.Data` project as an package dependeny to the `WinUI3.MigrationStartup` project
4. Change the migration command to `Add-Migration InitialCreate -Verbose -Project WinUI3.Data -StartupProject WinUI3.Data.Startup`

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444014/entity-framework-tools-not-working-with-uwp-apps-c-sharp) for more information